# Fetch random row from group by query (mysql) in Cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a table 'activities' and the columns are grouped by three of its attributes. Now I want to fetch Activity ID that is randomly selected from all the set of groups. The query is as follows:

```
$act = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $cond,
        'limit' => $limit,
        'fields' => array('count(*) as count, Activity.id as id'),
        'page' => $page,
        'group' => $group,
));
```

These are the things I tried and none of them worked. 
1. Create a self join which should have random records

```
    $this->bindModel(array(
        'belongsTo' => array(
            'Random' => array(
                'className' => 'Activity',
                'order' => 'rand()',
                'foreignKey' => 'id',
                'fields' => 'Random.id'
            )
        )
    ));
```

This failed because the rand() order is appended in the end which simply randomizes all fetched activities.

1. Added a join option

   ```
       'joins' => array(
           array(
               'table' => 'activities',
               'alias' => 'Random',
               'type' => 'LEFT',
               'conditions' => array(
                   'Activity.id = Random.id'
               ),
               'fields' => 'Random.id',
               'order' => 'rand()'
           )
   ```

This also didn't work as order value is not parsed by Cake

1. Tried to add condition
   'Activity.id >= floor(rand() * (max(Activity.id) - min(Activity.id)) -    min(Activity.id))'
   Gave a mysql error

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured it out. We need to hack the way cake php works. In place of table name, I wrote a query to fetch randomly ordered records. Also notice the join type is 'right'. Left join wont produce randomly sorted list

```
    $activities = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $cond,
        'page' => $page,
        'limit' => $limit,
        'fields' => array('count(*) as count, Random.id as id, max(Activity.modified) as Modified'),
        'group' => $group,
        'order' => 'Modified desc',
        'joins' => array(                
            array(
                'table' => '(select * from activities order by rand())',
                'alias' => 'Random',
                'type' => 'RIGHT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Activity.id = Random.id'
                ),
            )
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your query is working:

```
$act = $this->find('all', array('conditions' => $cond,
    'limit' => $limit,
    'fields' => array('count(*) as count, Activity.id as id'),
    'page' => $page,
    'group' => $group,
    'order' => 'rand()',
    'limit' => '1' // if you only want one random activity ID
));
```

Comment: Mysql returns the first activity from the grouped activities. I need this to be random among all grouped rows.

Comment: Can you give a sample data of activities and the groups? As well as your sample expected output. Your question is somehow confusing.